# Is there any way to avoid nested "for" loops in java

Tags: java, data-structures, nested-loops

so I'm solving a coding challenge and my code failed in test cases with large number of inputs due to timeout.

I need to do a simulation of "count" times.
each simulation will produce a random number between 0 and 364 of "size" times
each number should be stored and counted if two numbers are stored in the same index that mean the count is '2' then Hits++
return the percentage of hits with respect to "count"

```
public double calculate(int size, int count) {
        // TODO -- add your code here
        int Hits=0;
        for(int j=1;j<=count;j++) {        // number of simulation 

            int BirthDays[]=new int[365];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            rnd.setSeed(j);

            for(int i=0;i<size;i++){      //number of people  
                int x=rnd.nextInt(365);
                BirthDays[x]=BirthDays[x]+1;
                if(BirthDays[x]>=2){
                    Hits++;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        return(((float)Hits/count)*100);

    }
```

so is there any way to reduce the time complexity ? 
the data structure can be changed it is not exclusive to arrays .

Comment: @Jiri You don't like 'Hey'?

Comment: @AdriaanKoster That actually wasn't me, see revision history. I didn't like the extra quote in title :)

Comment: @TheBakker How would that help?

Comment: @Ahmed Matar How did the code timeout?  It seems okay to me.

Comment: Perhaps unrelated to the question itself - the `365` constants in code should probably be replaced by `size`.

Comment: @Jiri ah yes, I see. Sry

Comment: @JiriTousek 365 is the number of days in the year . sorry i should have pointed that

Comment: @SteveSmith well i submitted it and that's the error message "Grader timed out while grading your submission. Please try submitting an optimized solution"

Comment: Why are you calling setSeed()?

Comment: @AdriaanKoster  it obligatory in the assignment . to make sure the results are always the same for all students . it's their way to be able to auto grade the assignment .

Comment: which values are you testing with?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer the count value ranges between 5000 and 50000. size between 1 and 50

Comment: how do you get a timeout at a max of less then 100ms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest time saver I see immediately is to move `Random rnd = new Random()` out of the loop. You don't need to create a new instance each time and it is quite slow.

```
public double calculate(int size, int count) {       
    int max = 365;
    int birthDays[] = new int[max];
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int hits = 0;
    for(int j = 1; j <= count; j++) {
        Arrays.fill(birthDays, 0);
        rnd.setSeed(j);
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int x = rnd.nextInt(max);
            birthDays[x]++;
            if(birthDays[x] >=2 ) {
                hits++;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    return (hits/count) * 100;

}
```

Comment: And move the `int birthDays[] = new int[max];`, and do an `Arrays.fill` to zero it out inside the loop.

Comment: Will that be faster for sure?

Comment: I'd be literally amazed if it made a significant difference, as with any of the changes you propose here.

Comment: The only time saver I propose is moving the `new Random()` statement out of the loop. All my other changes so far are cosmetic.

Comment: So you're moving that out of the loop to save reallocating the object. What do you think moving the array creation out of the loop does?

Comment: Well, I knew that creating a new Random() is a very time consuming operation. I wasn't certain that Arrays.fill would be a lot faster than creating a new array, but a quick Google indeed suggests that it is.

Comment: And stop being so passive-aggressive please.

Comment: I wasn't intending to be passive aggressive, and I apologize if I came over that way. I was just trying to say that if you were going to avoid one repeated allocation, then you may as well do the other one too, and I was surprised that you seemed dubious that it would be faster. But actually, I am surprised that the array reallocation seems to be the expensive one - when I benchmarked it, moving the array allocation out of the loop roughly halved the running time.

Comment: Getting better, but note that `i` will usually only get to 20 or so before you hit a duplicate birthday (google birthday paradox).  You will save some time if you remember the 20 or so birthdays in a separate array and then reset those counts specifically instead of doing Arrays.fill() for all 365 days.